# How do I convert a string to a symbol for use as a key in the Lisp "assoc" function?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, symbols

I have this association-list in Common Lisp:

```
(defvar base-list (list (cons 'a 0) (cons 2 'c)))
```

I have to call `assoc` when my argument is of type `string`.

For the pair `(A . 0)` I have to convert "a" to a symbol, and for the pair `(2 . C)` I have to convert "2" to a symbol. How can I do that?

This should work like this:

```
CL-USER 28 : 1 > (assoc (convert-string-to-symbol "a") base-list)
(A . 0)
CL-USER 28 : 1 > (assoc (convert-number-to-symbol "2") base-list)
(2 . C)
```

I tried using `intern` but got `NIL`:

```
CL-USER 29 : 1 > (assoc (intern "a") base-list)
NIL
```

Comment: Hmm..this is similar but doesn't work!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9812393/elisp-how-to-delete-an-element-from-an-association-list-with-string-key

Comment: get out of the debugger.

Comment: The NUMBER-TO-SYMBOL part makes no sense, since the number 2 is no symbol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close with [`intern`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_intern.htm); you just had the case wrong. Try this:

```
> (assoc (intern "A") base-list)
(A . 0)
```

Note that here the name-as-string is capitalized.

Alternately, you could use [`find-symbol`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_find_s.htm#find-symbol) to look for an existing symbol by name:

```
> (assoc (find-symbol "A") base-list)
(A . 0)
```

The key here is that when you wrote your original `defvar` form, the *reader* read the string "a" and—by virtue of the current [*readtable case*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_r.htm#readtable_case)—converted the symbol name to be uppercase. Symbols with names of different case are not equal. It just so happens that at read time the reader is projecting what you wrote (lowercase) to something else (uppercase).

You can inspect the current case conversion policy for the current reader using the [`readtable-case`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rdtabl.htm) function:

```
> (readtable-case *readtable*)
:UPCASE
```

To learn more about how the readtable case and the reader interact, see the discussion in [section 23.1.2 of the Hyperspec.](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/23_ab.htm)

Answer (score 15):

The function you want is called `read-from-string`:

```
CL-USER> (read-from-string "a")
A
1
CL-USER> (read-from-string "2")
2
1
CL-USER>
```

Note that solutions based on using `intern` or `find-symbol` would not work for strings representing numbers (e.g., "2") on most implementations.